# Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'char' in HashSet.Contains Method

Tags: c#

Print first repeating character in the string given using C#. When running this getting error message.

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'char'

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main (string[] args) {
        string str = "fafaffaa";
        char[] ArrChar = str.ToCharArray ();
        Console.WriteLine ("First Repeating char :", MatChar (ArrChar));
    }
    public static char MatChar (char[] input) {
        HashSet<char> HasChar = new HashSet<char> ();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++) {
            char c = input[i];
            if (HasChar.Contains (c)) return c;
            else return HasChar.Add (c);
        }
        return '\0';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Getting this error because HasChar.Add() return bool. It return true if element added else false. So only getting this error, So use List instead of HashSet.
Can rewrite following


public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "faffaa";
            char[] ArrChar = str.ToCharArray();
            MatChar(ArrChar);
            Console.Read();
        }

        public static void MatChar(char[] input)
        {
            List<char> HasChar = new List<char>();
            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            {
                char c = input[i];
                if (HasChar.Contains(c))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("First repeating character: {0}", c);
                    break;
                }
                else
                    HasChar.Add(c);
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not return in the else case. Also, you forgot the placeholder in your format string

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str = "fafaffaa";
    char[] ArrChar = str.ToCharArray();
    Console.WriteLine("First Repeating char : {0}", MatChar(ArrChar));
}

public static char MatChar(char[] input)
{
    HashSet<char> HasChar = new HashSet<char>();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        char c = input[i];
        if (HasChar.Contains(c))
            return c;
        else
            HasChar.Add(c);
    }
    return '\0';
}
```

Comment: If the current char is not already seen, you need to continue the loop with the next one. If there are no repeating char, you will return `\0`. If the current char is known, it's returned.

Comment: for that i need to insert in HashSet know

Answer (score 1):

You have a return on the else condition.  I think your intention is that you just want to add to the HashSet.

```
if (HasChar.Contains(c)) return c; else HasChar.Add(c);
```

Comment: thank you for reply,yes but only if it is not contains